# Oracle get 1hr back date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In Oracle, I want to get specific intervals.

Consider, sysdate is 10-dec-2016 10:15:23 (dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss). I want to get a date period like 10-dec-2016 09:00:00 to 10-dec-2016 10:00:00

How to get this date period through query. If you have observed this date period is 1hr back from current HH24 format and rounded to 00:00. The query should work for whatever I set. Above date period is for 1hr. I should be able to set for any number of hours like 2hrs,3hrs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select trunc(your_date, 'hh') - number_of_hours_to_go_back/24 start_dt,
       trunc(your_date, 'hh') end_dt
from   dual;
```

if you need it in a SQL statement, or:

```
declare
  v_date date := to_date('10/12/2016 10:15:23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
  v_start_dt date;
  v_end_dt date;
  v_num_hours_back integer;
begin
  v_start_dt := trunc(v_date, 'hh') - v_num_hours_back/24;
  v_end_dt := trunc(v_date, 'hh');
end;
/
```

if you need it in PL/SQL (to save unnecessary context switching between SQL and PL/SQL).

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

But this is working for 1hr and above. can you customize this for even 1/2hr also? If current time is 10-dec-2016 10:45:00, I need date period  from 10-dec-2016 10:00:00 to 10-dec-2016 10:30:00

Comment: It would have helped if you could have included all your scenarios in your original question, so that we had a better idea of what you were after!

Comment: You are right. The query should work for 1/2hr,1hr,2hr etc.

Comment: Please go back and edit your question, providing a list of dates, the number of hours you're putting in and what you're expecting to see (in a tabular format). That way, we can easily see all your expected scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
WITH dt AS
  ( SELECT ROUND(sysdate,'HH') hour_date FROM dual
  )
SELECT hour_date - 1/24, hour_date FROM dt
```

1. Round date to nearest hour.
2. For oracle Date arithmetic, subtracting 1 from a DATE type is 24 hours, so 1/24 is one hour, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a generic function you can use for any interval which fits into "higher range"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;


select 
   MakeInterval(TO_TIMESTAMP('10-dec-2016 10:15:23', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), INTERVAL '1' HOUR) as time
from dual;
```

For other intervals use `INTERVAL '2' HOUR` or `INTERVAL '30' MINUTE`, etc.