# Breaking timestamp into hour intervals for each day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with data as follows. `CASE_ID` is `NUMBER` type while `TIMESTAMP` is `TIMESTAMP` type.

```
CASE_ID        TIMESTAMP
1              09-OCT-18 12.28.48.655904000
2              10-OCT-18 08.14.38.909903000
3              11-OCT-18 02.46.55.755881000
4              12-OCT-18 14.17.44.103901150
```

I’d like to have a select statement to which I add a third column `TIME_INTERVAL` to the returned results and from the above data so it is represented as follows:

```
CASE_ID        TIMESTAMP                         TIME_INTERVAL
1              09-OCT-18 12.28.48.655904000      09-OCT-18 12:00-13:00
2              10-OCT-18 08.14.38.909903000      10-OCT-18 08:00-09:00
3              11-OCT-18 02.46.55.755881000      11-OCT-18 02:00-03:00
4              12-OCT-18 14.17.44.103901150      12-OCT-18 14:00-15:00
```

Basically in `TIME_INTERVAL` I check from `TIMESTAMP` to see what hour interval the timestamp falls in and return it, so if a transaction was on `Oct 18 2018` at `20.20.15.216901550`, `TIME_INTERVAL` column would show as `18-OCT-18 20:00-21:00` as the time is between `20:00 (8 o’clock)` and `21:00 (9 o’clock)`. Any help?

Comment: `trunc(timestamp, 'hh')`?

Comment: Maybe use this generic function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104010/oracle-get-1hr-back-date/41106904#41106904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use :

```
select t.*, 
       to_char(trunc(cast ( timestamp  as date )     , 'hh24'), 
                    'dd-MON-rr hh24:mi','nls_date_language=english')
       ||' - '||
       to_char(trunc(cast ( timestamp  as date )+1/24, 'hh24'),
                              'hh24:mi')
       as TIME_INTERVAL           
  from tab t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't give us an easy way to try this out but the following should work:

```
select
       case_id
     , TIMESTAMP
     , extract(hour from TIMESTAMP) as started_at
     , extract(hour from TIMESTAMP)+1
```

Building a nice range string from the above two values is left as an exercise for the reader.